# Passing string array to c# web service (Android Ksoap2)

Tags: c#, android, web-services, ksoap2

Hi so i've been searching google for a while and but can't seem to have a solid example for this. I've been working with webservice this past few days with android and I can succesfully pass parameters from android and consume it back with ksoap with no problems. But now I need to pass an array to a webservice. So heres my sample web service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Sample(string[] logs)
{
    return array[0];
}
```

And this is the XML that I need to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Sample xmlns="http://MTKAndroidService.org/">
      <array>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </array>
    </Sample>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've been stuck with this for a while now and hope someone can help me.

Comment: what about just passing a comma-delimited string, then using `string[] array = String.Split(",",input);`

Comment: thank you for the reply. Yes i already ventured into that option but the string would be too long if i did it that way. We are talking of upto 100 string values here so i dont really think its best to use that technique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally Got it....for those who is stuck on this also ill post my answer

```
public String Sample()
    { 
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MTKAndroidService.org/Sample";
        String METHOD_NAME = "Sample";
//      URL =  "http://10.0.2.2:49923/Service1.asmx";   // to be adjusted to the URL above once this code is added into WebService;
        String IP_LIST="";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        List<String> logs =  new ArrayList<String>();
        logs.add("hello");
        logs.add("world");
        SoapObject soapLogs = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "logs");
        for (String i : logs){
            soapLogs.addProperty("string", i);
        }
        request.addSoapObject(soapLogs);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope IPenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        IPenvelope.dotNet = true;
        IPenvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try 
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, IPenvelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)IPenvelope.getResponse();
                Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
                IP_LIST= response.toString();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return IP_LIST;
    }
```

Comment: @TheProvots:pls. refer this link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198017/pass-arraylist-data-into-soap-web-service-in-android) Do you have any idea how can i send this type of data to soap service

Comment: Hi sorry been a long time since i logged in...anyway are you still having problem with this? i cannot seem to access your page

Comment: :refer link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353244/issue-in-passing-json-format-in-soap-service-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353244/issue-in-passing-json-format-in-soap-service-android) how can i pass this data ?